# Using Environmental Variables in Mirth Connect

Tags: hl7, mirth

Is it possible to use environmental variables in Mirth Connect in either the destination's Content or the destination's URL?
[image: URL]
or
[image: Content]

Answer (score 5):

Even if it's not possible directly, you always can use

```
var value = java.lang.System.getenv(varname);
```

in the Global Deploy Script, then add variables to global maps and access them in a usual way. The same code will work in other scripts.

Answer (score 1):

it is possible to use environement variables as stated [here](https://www.mirthcorp.com/community/forums/showthread.php?t=7871)

You should modify the deploy script to include :

```
$gc('env',java.lang.System.getenv());
return;
```

And the call should be as follow :

```
${env.get('HOME')}/Desktop/
```